# Why $\lim_{h→0+}\frac{ f (x + 2h) − f (x + h)}{h}$ is not a derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f :\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with the property that
$\lim_{h→0+}\frac{ f (x + 2h) − f (x + h)}
{h} = 0$, for all $x ∈ \mathbb R$.
Prove that $f$ is constant

I’m not asking for a solution to this problem, I’m interested in why what is written cannot be considered a definition of a derivative.
We can take $t=x+h$ and then $\lim_{h→0+}\frac{ f (t+h) − f (t)} {h} = 0$ and this is the definition of derivative.

Or is the problem in $\lim_{h→0+}$  ,but  $f$ is a continuous function, which means $\lim_{h→0+}f(x+h)=\lim_{h→0-}f(x+h)$

I will be glad if you can help me understand this problem.

Comment: Your $t$ depends on $h$ so it is NOT the definition of a derivative.

Comment: $t$ is not a fixed point. It depends on $h$ so you cannot talk about the derivative at $t$.

Comment: Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{$x$ is rational}\\-1,&\text{$x$ is irrational.}\end{cases}$$ Then $f'(0)$ is undefined but under this definition of derivative $f'(0)$ would be $0$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Your too trivial example does not meet the continuity requirement...

Comment: @SergeBallesta The exercise is to show that continuity implies the function being constant, so of course any non-trivial example is not going to be continuous.

Comment: @BrunoB: I just wondered whether under the hypothesis of continuity (or maybe absolute continuity) the existence of OP's limit was or not enough to ensure derivability. But I could not conclude yet :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuity doesn't imply differentiability and therefore

$$\lim_{h→0^+}\frac{ f (x + 2h) − f (x + h)}{h}=2\lim_{h→0^+}\frac{ f (x + 2h) − f (x)}{2h}-\lim_{h→0^+}\frac{ f (x + h) − f (x )}{h}=f'(x)$$

is not true in general.

Comment: As far as I understand, the main problem is that the derivative may not exist at some points. That is, if we knew that $f$ is differentiable, then this expression would be a derivative

Comment: @didenkojack Yes exactly, only continuity doesn't suffice to conclude easily (and I don't think it holds in general) at least we need Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: A constant function is Lipschitz continuous with any Lipschitz constant $k \ge 0$, so the statement $\lim_{h→0+}\frac{ |f (x + 2h) − f (x + h)|}{h}=0 \iff k=0$ is wrong. – It *may* be that $\lim_{h→0+}\frac{ |f (x + 2h) − f (x + h)|}{h}=0 $ together with Lipschitz continuity implies that $f$ is constant, but that needs to be proven.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, you are completely right. For the moment I let the first part and I'll revise the second part later.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but which of the two equalities fails? Both look right to me :|

Answer (score 4):

Avika Weinberger made a comment with a nice example what could go wrong with this alternative definition for non-continuous $f$. If $f$ is continuous and obeys the limit the OP imposed, then fix an arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}$, arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and suppose $\delta>0$ is so small that $\forall h \in (0,\delta)$
$$|f(x+2h)-f(x+h)|\leq \varepsilon h/2.$$
Because of the continuity of $f$ we can conclude that $\forall h \in (0,+\infty)$ there exists $N_h\in \mathbb{N}_0$ s.t.
$$|f(x+2^{-N_h}h)-f(x)|\leq \varepsilon h/2.$$
Then for all $h\in (0,\delta)$ we have
$$\left|f(x+h)-f(x)\right|\leq \left(\sum_{j=0}^{N_h-1} |f(x+2^{-j}h)-f(x+2^{-j-1}h)|\right)+|f(x+2^{-N_h}h)-f(x)| \\
\leq \left(\sum_{j=0}^{N_h-1} \varepsilon 2^{-j-2}h\right)+\varepsilon h/2 \leq \varepsilon h.$$
So $f$ is differentiable at $x$ with $f'(x)=0$. Now you can conclude through Lagrange's theorem that $f$ must be a constant function.